# How do I make sure that all of my blocks don't get destroyed when I click to destroy one of them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where you have to click on blocks to destroy them to move the player from the top of the tower to the bottom safely (the tower is made out of the blocks). I have a script that destroys the block that is clicked that works on a few of the blocks but when I press some of the blocks multiple or all of the blocks are destroyed and I don't know why.

Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DestroyObjectOnClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector2 mousePos2D = new Vector2(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mousePos2D, Vector2.zero);
            if (hit.collider != null)
            {
               gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
    }
}
}
```

[Here's my hierarchy (just in case it's needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr8fB.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there is no indication in your code that you need to destroy exactly the object that was clicked with the mouse. If this code is used on several objects, then, according to the logic of the code, if you hit somewhere when you click the mouse, every object on which this code is used will be destroyed.

use
`hit.collider.gameObject.SetActive(false);` 
instead of
`gameObject.SetActive(false);`

This will solve your problem. And it is enough to assign it to any one indestructible object on the scene, and not to each destructible block. In order not to destroy the excess - enter an additional check in the "if".